# Newer version of git installed on OSX but not being used. How can I find it and use it?

Tags: linux, macos, git, unix, environment-variables

I'm trying to update git from the default mac version to a newer version. I already have a newer version installed (as seen below) but I don't know where it is.

```
Aarons-iMac:~ AaronWilliamson$ cd
Aarons-iMac:~ AaronWilliamson$ git --version
-bash: git: command not found
Aarons-iMac:~ AaronWilliamson$ brew upgrade git
Error: git 2.2.2 already installed
```

How can I locate the path to where git 2.2.2 is installed so I can use it? I'm a beginner and am in the process of understanding the concepts of environment variables and the $PATH variable.

For reference, here are the contents of my `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH=/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh
export PATH=./bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh
source ~/.profile
export PGDATA=/usr/local/var/postgres
export PGHOST=/tmp
export PGDATA=/usr/local/var/postgres
export PGHOST=/tmp
export PGDATA=/usr/local/var/postgres
export PGHOST=/tmp
export PGDATA=/usr/local/var/postgres
export PGHOST=/tmp

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" #             Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Also, in another answer, it was recommended to rename the default mac version of git to another name which I did from `git` to `git-apple`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The default git should be in `/usr/bin` I dont recall if that is in `$PATH` by default or not, though i would think it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
brew link git
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you @pablopunk, this fixed the issue. Could you by chance explain why this was needed in my case or why it wasn't working?

Comment: @wikea1 Well, homebrew usually install stuff in /usr/local/Cellar/ and then it links it to a path like the ones you got, but sometimes there are problems with these links, although the programas are still installed, they're just not linked.